# Does Microsoft Application Insights support MVC 6 (.Net 5)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to setup a prototype with an mvc 6 project and application insights.  When selecting to monitor an mvc 6 website in IIS 7, it says it is monitoring but no server statistics are being sent to Azure.  When I monitor any other sites on that server it works correctly.  So my question is, does application insights support .Net 5 and MVC 6 running in IIS?

In the website I have installed Application Insights using the snippet of javascript provided by Microsoft Application Insights.  This is working correctly and sending data to Azure.

The website is on a local Windows 2012 server.  I have installed the  Application Insights Status Monitor on the server and I have it pointed to the mvc 6 website.  This part is not working.  When I point the Server Tool to a site on the local server running a .Net 4.5 website it does submit the data correctly to Azure.

I did not add the AI part via nuget package because I am not submitting any custom alerts to Applications Insight.  Right now I am just looking to get the server statistics.  IE Memory, Processor usage, etc.

Comment: Can you add some more information on how / where you are adding the insights etc..

Comment: are you adding the AI nuget packages in your project?  are you using status monitor?  is it an azure website, etc?  we need more information to help you.

Comment: Hey John, I have added more details.  Let me know if you need more information.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ongoing work visible on it in github: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetv5

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net vnext is not currently supported. But there are plans to support it in the near future.